# datatable to datatable linq filter

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am trying to take a main datatable, and pull a subset of data from it into another table. I cannot figure out how to get my LINQ syntax correct.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("start...");

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("fn", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("ln", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("EN", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Role", typeof(string));

        Object[] rows = {
                             new Object[]{"Jane","Smith",123456,"Admin"},
                             new Object[]{"Jane","Smith",123456,"Test"},
                             new Object[]{"Jane","Smith",123456,"QA"},
                             new Object[]{"John","Doe",23456,"Admin"},
                             new Object[]{"John","Doe",23456,"Test"},
                             new Object[]{"John","Doe",23456,"Manager"},
                             new Object[]{"John","Doe",23456,"Approver"},
                             new Object[]{"Princess","Peach",12345,"Admin"},
                             new Object[]{"Princess","Peach",12345,"Test"},
                             new Object[]{"Princess","Peach",12345,"QA"}
                         };

        foreach(Object[] row in rows)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }


        DataTable o = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(x => x.Field<string>("EN") == 123456)
            .CopyToDataTable();

        for(int i =0; i <o.Rows.Count-1; ++i)
        {
            for(int x=0; x<o.Columns.Count; ++x)
            {
                Console.Write("{0}\t", o.Rows[i][x].ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }


        Console.WriteLine("fin...");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

So what I would want in the resulting set would be records for Jane Smith. I also tried using

```
DataTable.Select("EN = 123456");
```

but that returns me a DataRow[] and I really want it to be in a table object.

Comment: `x => x.Field<string>("EN") == 123456` - why not `x => x.Field<int>("EN") == 123456`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
DataTable o = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .Where(x => x.Field<int>("EN") == 123456)
                .CopyToDataTable();
```

Since your type for the field is `int`.

You can also compare first and last name like:

```
DataTable o = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x => x.Field<string>("fn") == "Jane" &&
                x.Field<string>("ln") == "Smith")
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

If you want to perform case insensitive comparison then use `String.Equals` overload and supply appropriate `StringComparison` value.

Comment: ugh- so dumb... thanks- been staring at that wondering why.. the error on intellisense wasn't clear until you pointed that out- i thought it was having an issue with just the "==" in the lambda, not the fact i was comparing a string/int field /faceplam.. I have to wait a few minutes to accept answer.